# system.getenv() property doesnt read the file path of the external logback.xml file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, logback

I have included the `logback.xml` file outside the classpath and used the

```
System.setProperty(
    ContextInitializer.CONFIG_FILE_PROPERTY,
    System.getenv("logging.config")
);
```

to read the file from a system variable.

This approach worked for me in a spring boot application but when I used the same thing in a maven project it doesn't read the file path. The file location is the same for both projects.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty(
        ContextInitializer.CONFIG_FILE_PROPERTY,
        System.getenv("logging.config")
    );
    System.out.println(System.getenv("logging.config"));
}
```

The program compiles without any errors but the logs are not displayed in the console.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing something wrong cause Spring Boot already supports scenarios like this. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html (The configuration can be given by command line)? No need to implement such things yourself...

Comment: Where and how do you set the property `logging.conf`?

Comment: @SubOptimal its the system variable name where i have specified the file path and im accessing the path through the system variable name. 
eg :C:\Users\Desktop\logback\logback.xml

Comment: The question is more where do you add the `-Dlogging.config=...` when you start your Maven project.

Comment: @SubOptimal i want to add it as an environment variable or a system variable not a java variable

Comment: Sorry I misread that point. So I will rephrase my question. Where do you set the environment variable `logging.conf`? If `System.getenv("logging.config")` doe not return a value it means the variable is not set for the running process.